# Trying to get my horse through a nether portal

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any ways I can get my **horse** into the nether without it suffocating in the portal and dying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default 4x8 nether frame should already be large enough to fit your horse without you suffocating, but if you're still experiencing an issue with suffocation you can make a larger nether frame. With Minecraft's 1.7.2 update the size limit of Nether Portal frames was made as large as 23x23 blocks of obsidian - more than large enough for your horse, or any creature really.

Answer (score 0):

It’s also a good idea to make sure your horse is on a lead and that there is a platform on the other side of the portal. This will ensure your horse doesn’t die.